# Node js-> python script. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'joblib' for the imported modules

Tags: node.js, python-3.x

I am trying to call the python script from my node js code. It works fine for the print function in the python code with the below code

**Node JS code**

```
  const { spawn } = require('child_process');
  const pyProg = spawn('python', ['app.py']);  
  pyProg.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log(data.toString());  
  });
  pyProg.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log('Error-->'+ data);
  });
```

**Working Python code app.py**

```
print('Hello')
```

However if in the script I include import joblib or any python modules such as

**Python script**

```
import joblib
import sys
def getGenre(age,sex):
  print(age)
  print(sex)
  input=[[0, 0]]
  input[0][0]=age
  input[0][1]=sex
  print(input)
  model=joblib.load('testModel.joblib')
  prediction=model.predict(input)
  print(prediction)

print('Start')
getGenre(50, 1)
print('End')
```

It is failing with the following error.

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'joblib' for the imported modules**

Can anyone suggest, what am I missing.

Comment: Do you have the joblib installed? Does the Python script work correct separately from the node part?

Comment: @bereal Yes the python script works correctly when executed separately in pycharm. The same script when copied in the vscode and executing is not working, given unable to find these libs which exists in \venv\Lib\site-packages in my pycharm project. How to get those in my vscode project is a question. I tried copying the libs but still it isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to do it by explicitly installing the python modules before execution using the below code

**Python**

```
import os
import sys
os.system('python3 -m pip install {}'.format(sys.argv[1]))
os.system('python3 -m pip install {}'.format(sys.argv[2]))
os.system('python3 -m pip install {}'.format(sys.argv[3]))
```

**Node**

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const pyProg = spawn('python', ['pyfiles/install_package.py',"joblib","sklearn","pandas"]);

pyProg.stdout.on('data', function(data) {

    console.log(data.toString());  
});
pyProg.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log('Error-->'+ data);
});
```

Comment: thank you for yout answer it helped me a lot.
I think you can put directly the dependencies in the python file, without putting it as arguments in the node file :)